# Future language support for Azure Speech API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm currently working on a project that makes use of the Azure Speech API and I've seen the current documentation on language support. My two questions are...

Is there is a road-map somewhere for future additions to the language support list? Specifically, will there be an standard voice added for Urdu?

And also, for our South Asian friends. I know Urdu and Hindi are different written; but if I understand correctly, they are similar spoken. Are they similar enough to listen for Hindi (supported by Speech-to-text) for both?